# Running two domains on one VPS

Tags: apache, dns, hosting, vps

This is my httpd.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/joshhornby
ServerName www.joshhornby.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/designerschool
ServerAlias www.designer-school.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If you go to joshhornby.co.uk then you will see that it takes you to the correct location and the site loads up with out issue. Going to designer-school.com doesn't load the correct files instead just loads joshhornby.co.uk with no stylesheets.

Where am I going wrong? Both domains are pointing at the same DNS and that DNS is running off the same server. I am trying to run two domains from on VPS. I have tried googling and nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.joshhornby.co.uk
ServerAlias joshhornby.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/joshhornby
ServerName www.joshhornby.co.uk</pre>
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.designer-school.com
ServerAlias designer-school.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/designerschool
ServerAlias www.designer-school.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is the error i get when resarting the server Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 996 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1001: <VirtualHost> was not closed.\n/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:996: <VirtualHost> was not closed.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trail and error i finally got this working

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName joshhornby.com
ServerAlias joshhornby.co.uk
DocumentRoot /var/www/joshhornby
ServerName www.joshhornby.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName joshornby.com
ServerAlias designer-school.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/designerschool
ServerAlias www.designer-school.com
</VirtualHost>
```